# jQuery index selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I'm trying to find out a way to know the index of a anchor tag inside a certain div (one div has multiple similar anchor tags), like this :

```
<div>
  <a>first</a>
  <a>second</a>
  <a>third</a>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery, but so far found no sollution to find the index of the anchor I have the mouse currently over.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
$('div a').mouseover(
function(){
  alert( $('div a').index(this) );
}
);
```

some changes would be required if there are multiple divs with links inside them and you want to find the index in that specific group..

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div a").hover(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
});
```

This is what you mean, am I correct?